# Should tripwire be entering /proc?

Tags: linux, ubuntu, tripwire

When initializing the db with tripwire --init  it spat out a bunch of errors pertaining to /proc:

```
### Warning: File system error.
### Filename: /proc/16982/fd/4
### No such file or directory
### Continuing...
### Warning: File system error.
### Filename: /proc/16982/fdinfo/4
### No such file or directory
### Continuing...
### Warning: File system error.
### Filename: /proc/16982/task/16982/fd/4
### No such file or directory
### Continuing...
### Warning: File system error.
### Filename: /proc/16982/task/16982/fdinfo/4
### No such file or directory
### Continuing...
### Warning: Duplicate object encountered.
### /proc/sys/net/ipv6/neigh
```

This feels like noise. The   `twpol.txt`  file has the following clause:

```
#
# Critical devices
#
(
  rulename = "Devices & Kernel information",
  severity = $(SIG_HI),
)
{
        /dev            -> $(Device) ;
        /proc           -> $(Device) ;
}
```

Which, if I understand it right, is going to cause tripwire to care deeply about the entire contents of /proc.  Shouldn't it just care about the static parts of /proc  like the drivers and such, and not the per-pid stuff?    Why does it ship like this?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I found this post on [LinuxQuestions](http://www.linuxquestions.org/questions/linux-security-4/tripwire-check-with-error-messages-related-to-proc-933616/#post4622856).

Modify so only intreresting parts of proc will be examined

```
# /proc -> $(Device) ;
/proc/sys -> $(Device) ;
/proc/cpuinfo -> $(Device) ;
/proc/modules -> $(Device) ;
```

Comment: Although that answers "How do I resolve this issue?", it does not answer the question: "Why is `/proc` included?". But I would imagine it's more of a mistake and lack of fixing tripwire long term... (since it's still there 10 years later)

Answer (score 2):

If its that much of a bother to you, you can modify your policy to exclude the folder from its scans....

to exclude /proc you could add something like:

```
   !/proc
```

to your policy and rebuild the database.